# binary tree and botkey troube - cannot traverse the tree

Tags: java

i'm doing a project and its to do with binary trees and botanical keys, now what i need to do load a bot key into the programme, then work be able to work my way through it going to each node in order to determine the type of tree it is, and it will display the tree itis when i reach a leaf node. Now im having trouble with the moving through it part, i cant figure out how to get it to work, ive tried many different things including a pre oder traversal, and i was just wondering if anyone could give me a hand in getting it off the ground so to speak. the code for the part of the programme i need to edit is below, the "chooseOption" method is the method used to traverse the tree.
thanks in advance.

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
*
* @author Alex Drinkwater 10077473
*/
public class BotKey implements IBotKey {

private Node root;
private Node currentNode;
// This stack will come in handy when you implement the "undo" facility
private Stack<Node> choiceStack = new Stack<Node>();

@Override
public boolean isLoaded() {
    return root != null;
}

@Override
public int getNbrChildren() {
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return currentNode.getNbrChildren();
    }
}

@Override
public String getLeadStatement(int i) {
    return currentNode.getChildStatement(i);
}

@Override
public void chooseOption(int i) {
    //You need to implement this method

    if (root != null) {
        root.getChildNode(i);
        root.getChildStatement(i);

    }


}

@Override
public void undoChoice() {
    //You need to implement this method
}

@Override
public String getResults() {
    //Dummy implementation. You need to supply a proper one
    if (currentNode.isLeaf() == true) {
        currentNode.getName();
    }
    else{
        String s =currentNode + "";
        if(currentNode!= null){
        }
    }
    return "s";

}


   @Override
   public void loadExample1() {
    Node southernLive = new Node("Southern live Oak: Quercus virginiana");
    Node dwarfLive = new Node("Dwarf live oak: Quercus minima");
    Node willow = new Node("Willow oak");
    Node shingle = new Node("Shingle oak");
    Node blackJack = new Node("Blackjack Oak");
    Node northernRed = new Node("Northern red oak");
    Node white = new Node("White oak Quercus alba");
    Node swampChestnut = new Node("Swamp chestnut oak Quercus prinus");


    Node node7 = new Node();
    node7.addChild(white, "Leaves with 5-9 deep lobes");
    node7.addChild(swampChestnut, "Leaves with 21-27 shallow lobes");

    Node node6 = new Node();
    node6.addChild(blackJack, "Leaves mostly with 3 lobes");
    node6.addChild(northernRed, "Leaves mostly with 7-9 lobes");

    Node node5 = new Node();
    node5.addChild(node7,
            "Lobes or teeth rounded or blunt-pointed, no bristles");
    node5.addChild(node6, "Lobes or teeth bristle-tipped");

    Node node4 = new Node();
    node4.addChild(willow, "Leaf narrow, about 4-6 times as long as broad");
    node4.addChild(shingle, "Leaf broad, about 2-3 times as long as broad");

    Node node3 = new Node();
    node3.addChild(dwarfLive, "Mature plant a small shrub");
    node3.addChild(southernLive, "Mature plant a large tree");

    Node node2 = new Node();
    node2.addChild(node4, "Leaves not evergreen");
    node2.addChild(node3, "Leaves evergreen");

    Node node1 = new Node();
    node1.addChild(node5, "Leaves usually with teeth or lobes");
    node1.addChild(node2, "Leaves usually without teeth or lobes");


    root = node1;
    currentNode = root;
}

@Override
public void loadExample2() {
    Node southernLive = new Node("Southern live Oak: Quercus virginiana");
    Node dwarfLive = new Node("Dwarf live oak: Quercus minima");
    Node willow = new Node("Willow oak");
    Node shingle = new Node("Shingle oak");
    Node blackJack = new Node("Blackjack Oak");
    Node northernRed = new Node("Northern red oak");
    Node white = new Node("White oak Quercus alba");
    Node swampChestnut = new Node("Swamp chestnut oak Quercus prinus");


    Node node7 = new Node();
    node7.addChild(white, "Leaves with 5-9 deep lobes");
    node7.addChild(swampChestnut, "Leaves with 21-27 shallow lobes");

    Node node6 = new Node();
    node6.addChild(blackJack, "Leaves mostly with 3 lobes");
    node6.addChild(northernRed, "Leaves mostly with 7-9 lobes");

    Node node5 = new Node();
    node5.addChild(node7,
            "Lobes or teeth rounded or blunt-pointed, no bristles");
    node5.addChild(node6, "Lobes or teeth bristle-tipped");

    Node node4 = new Node();
    node4.addChild(willow, "Leaf narrow, about 4-6 times as long as broad");
    node4.addChild(shingle, "Leaf broad, about 2-3 times as long as broad");

    Node node3 = new Node();
    node3.addChild(dwarfLive, "Mature plant a small shrub");
    node3.addChild(southernLive, "Mature plant a large tree");

    Node node2 = new Node();
    node2.addChild(node4, "Leaves not evergreen");
    node2.addChild(node3, "Leaves evergreen");

    Node node1 = new Node();
    node1.addChild(node5, "Leaves usually with teeth or lobes");
    node1.addChild(node2, "Leaves usually without teeth or lobes");


    root = node1;
    currentNode = root;

    //You need to implement this method
}

@Override
public void readFromFile(FileInputStream fs) {
    //You need to implement this method

    // You may find that a hashmap like this is useful
    HashMap<Integer, Node> map = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();
}

@Override
public boolean canUndo() {
    //Dummy implementation. You need to provide a proper one
    if (choiceStack != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a botanical "database" (in tree structure), that describes each plant, for example: "Willow oak"? Then you want to understand what was given for the search? For example we have a description of some plant: "Leaves with 5-9 deep lobes" and we want to get all plants that this plant could be? In that case we need to find a Node wich contains text "Leaves with 5-9 deep lobes". Let's call this node startingNode.

Then we have to move from startingNode to it's parent. Let's call startingNode's parent a parentNode. Then we have to get a parent of parentNode and so on. Repeat until you reach a node which has a name for the plant.